# How to use variables you get from an ajax request along with other variables and use them in a function?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using an ajax request to display some user input variables that i get from a javascript pop up form. I have my index.php which contains the pop up form and the ajax request the source code is the following:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog">

   <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Input parameters</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="form-control-label">Enter you Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message-text" class="form-control-label">Enter your message:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="message-text">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Close
                </button>
                <button id="paramsOkay" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Okay
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>



   <div id="content"></div>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#myModal').on('click','#paramsOkay', function (e) {
          //var x = console.log($('#recipient-name').val());
          //var y = console.log($('#message-text').val());
           var x = $('#recipient-name').val();
           var y = $('#message-text').val(); 
           var xy = (x+","+y);
             $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"action.php",
             data:{name:xy},
             success:function(result){
             $("#content").html(result);
             }
             });

    //console.log(e);
       });

    })

    </script>




    </body>
</html>
```

and my action.php which is used to dispaly the variabels as php variables

action.php

```
<?php

$string = $_POST["name"];
echo $string;//string that contains the name and the message ina single line as follows (name,message) 
echo "<br>";

$name = strstr($string, ',',true);
echo $name; // prints just the name 

echo "<br>";

$message = substr($string, strpos($string, ",") + 1);    
echo $message;// prints just the message without the semicolon


?>
```

What i want to do is instead of echo the variables from the action.php i want to use them in a function along with some others variables that i have in my index.php how can  pass them to my index.php insted of just dispalying them?

Comment: to confirm: you want to pass them to a PHP function in index.php? or a JavaScript function in index.php?

Comment: in a php function

Comment: Surely that somewhat defies the point of using ajax in the first place as you'd have to reload index.php in order for the PHP to run..

Comment: Yeah but i had to use ajax in order to get the variables from the pop up form and be able to use them later, i am using a php function that is connecting with firebase in this function i pass the tittle, the message and some other variables that are needed so that the whole function will be able to be executed i have all of the variabels stored in php variables in my index.php and i just need the user to provide me with the message tittel and message when i have all of them i i will be able to run the function

Comment: Can you not just use a regular form submission and `post` the data (the variables from the popup form) to index.php?

Comment: i already done that but it looks much nicer when i use a modal, and i thought of doing that ass well :)

Comment: Nono you can still use a modal. What I mean is that to run your PHP code in index.php, your page which contains the modal will need to reload. So rather than going index.php -> ajax -> action.php -> index.php, I don't see why you aren't just going index.php -> Index.php. Surely it would look exactly the same to the user...

Comment: Yeah i get what you are saying , i just did it like that because its gonna execute all the php code first and then it will execute the javascript code, so when i first run the page i will probably get an error that my post variables are undefined , thats why i am using another php file